# Clicking lable which is behind picture box

Tags: c#

There is a picture box and its onto a lable and when mouse enters the picture box's visibility is turned to false so that the label is shown the problem is I want to make the lable clickable but it's not working ..... I think the mouse enter event is blocking the click every thing is coded I didn't use the drag and drop thing.

Comment: are you using windows forms or wpf?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ TAG your question correctly! - Also: You need to show your code. I tested here and found it to work just fine. Did you even code the Click event?

Comment: Sorry am new here I nvr asked a question here before ......it was a winform but I figured it out thanks anyways

Answer (score -1):

If you double click on the label in Winform designer that should take you to the OnClick method for the label. There you can specify what you want to do when the user clicks on it. If you have done this and cant click or see the label. In designer place the label on top of the image, make the label not visible until the picture is hovered then click label.